# PowerBI API | Import PBIX

Tags: c#, powerbi

I have a method to upload a .PBIX file to my PowerBI App, This method return a id as expected. However the reports and datasets doesn't appear on PowerBI

My Method :

```
   public static string SendFile()
        {

            string[] files = { "D://David/Documents//PBIX_TEST.pbix" };


            string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/imports?datasetDisplayName=PBI_TESTT");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            //httpWebRequest./*Credentials*/ = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", nsToken.TokenSingleton.Instance.token.AccessToken));
            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition:  form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";
            string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "fieldNameHere", "PBIX_TEST.pbix");
                //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", files[i]);
                byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
                memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            memStream.Close();
            requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            try
            {
                WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                string var = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var dataset = (dataset)jsonSerializer.Deserialize(var, typeof(dataset));
                return dataset.Id;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            httpWebRequest = null;
        }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

David Almas
PT-PT

Answer (score 0):

If you do GET .../imports/{import id you received}, it will return to you the IDs for the dataset and report once they are finished being created.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct I think.  I used it when I was coding my solution, which uses the HttpClient approach.

The [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243840.aspx) isn't very specific, but the dataSetDisplayName query string parameter is required, which I see you have done.

Also, the API docs don't mention it, but groups are supported here.  Here's my code, which is working as expected.

```
        public async Task<UploadFileResponse> UploadImportAsync(string displayName, Guid? groupId = null, ConflictInstruction conflictInstruction = ConflictInstruction.None)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(displayName), "Display name cannot be null");
        await AcquireTokenAsync();

        string url = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/imports/?dataSetDisplayName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(displayName);

        if (groupId.HasValue)
        {
            url = string.Concat("https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/groups/", groupId, "/imports/?datasetDisplayName=", displayName);
        }

        if (conflictInstruction != ConflictInstruction.None)
        {
            url += "&nameConflict=" + conflictInstruction;
        }

        //just a test file
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\chris\Documents\Power BI\FarmData.pbix");

        string fileName = "Myfile.pbix";

        var result = await PerformFileUploadAsync(url, bytes, fileName);
        UploadFileResponse uploadFileResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadFileResponse>(result, serializerSettings);

        return uploadFileResponse;
    }
```

and then the meat of the process:

```
 private async Task<string> PerformFileUploadAsync(string url, byte[] bytes, string fileName)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "true");
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

                string boundary = string.Concat("---------------------------", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                MultipartFormDataContent requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);

                ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-zip-compressed");
                byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "file0", FileName = fileName };

                requestContent.Add(byteArrayContent);

                request.Content = requestContent;

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                    var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        return responseData;

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine("Url:" + url);
                    sb.AppendLine("Method: " + HttpMethod.Post);
                    sb.AppendLine("HttpStatusCode: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
                    sb.AppendLine("Unable to retrieve data from service: " + responseData);
                    Log.Error(sb.ToString());
                    throw new HttpException((int)response.StatusCode, responseData);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }                    
        }                                                                
    }
```